# How to check the Nullability of a field in Mockito null-safey support

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, tdd

I want to check, for example, if a received field from API is null or not. I want to make an arrangement actually.

```
when(tFinalizeRegistrationResponse.token).thenReturn(null);
```

But in null-safety, we can not return null in thenReturn method. How can I achieve this?

Comment: "But in null-safety, we can not return null in thenReturn method." That premise is not correct. [`thenReturn`](https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/mockito/PostExpectation/thenReturn.html) returns a generic type, which can be a nullable type.  If you can't use `.thenReturn(null)`, then `tFinalizeRegistrationResponse.token` does not return a nullable type and therefore can never be `null`.